# Converting pandas series to 3D input vectors for LSTM implementation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lstm

I have a pandas series where each row is a list sequence containing 50 timesteps each as input and another series with corresponding 10 timestep sequences as output. The shape of their heads is (5,) respectively. I wish to convert the training data to a shape (n_samples, 50, 1) and test data to a shape (n_samples, 10) in order to feed it to a **many-to-many LSTM model**. I've been trying several approaches on Stackoverflow but none of them seem to be working for me. Whatever I do, I keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

[image: a snapshot of what the data looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague helped me with the answer to this:

```
N = 100 #number of samples
X = df_new['sequence']
y = df_new['target']
X = X.iloc[:N]
X = np.array([[np.array(x) for x in X.values]]).T.reshape(N, 50, 1)
y = y.iloc[:N]
y = np.array([np.array(x) for x in y.values])
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
```

The part I missed was the use of the transpose function to manipulate the arrays.